# Nothingburger -- Where did it come from

Tags: etymology

The expression "nothingburger" to mean in essence "nothing to see here" has become extremely common in political discourse in the USA. From what I remember it really only became prominent in the last two or three years.

What is the origin of this rather odd word, and what provoked the very recent spike in its usage?

(BTW, please, no politically provocative comments in your answer.)

Comment: I hope 'where's the beef' is not provocative.

Comment: Nothingburger and "no there there" would be synonymous. "No there there" is really quite funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etymology of **Nothingburger**:

The metaphorical use of a burger missing a patty (compare Where's the beef?), coined by Hollywood movie columnist Louella Parsons and first used in her daily gossip column "Louella's Move-Go-'Round" of June 1, 1953

What has increased is its use of late ... I refuse to answer on grounds it may incriminate me.  But a friend told me it may have to do with multiple issues revolving around #fakenews!

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nothingburger